# Convert Latitude / Longitude coordinates to physical address

Tags: ios, core-location

I am using Core Location in my app to track the current location of the users phone. As of now I am successful in getting the lat / long, but now I want to display the address of the lat / long into a Label. I.E 123 Fifteenth St. NY NY 123456.

Any suggestions as to how I can go about converting the coordinates to the address they are currently at?

Comment: FYI this process is called "reverse geocoding"; searching for that might help you find more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once I have tried `MapQuest API` with open data, you can try it. For me it worked brilliantly:

http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/

They have well described `API` with quite many features :) you just need to retrieve a key. They do have even `iOS SDK`:

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/apple-ios-maps-api

I have tried it in one projected and it worked nicely.

**EDIT**

If you want to stick with Apple solutions then you should take a look at [reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:) method which should be sufficient to solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following method `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:` of the CLGeocoder class.

Reference: [CLGeocoder Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation%3acompletionHandler%3a)